# Доступ к сервису Rest Api по IP (IIS)

Tags: c#, rest, iis, hosting

Создал на амазоновском (`Windows Server 2019`) сервере `IIS` сервер  и разместил свой `rest api server`.  Если я пытаюсь получить данные через `localhost/api/getplace/1` на этом же компьютере, то все нормально возвращается. Если же я на этом же компьютере вызываю через публичный `IP` `http://xx.xxx.xxx.106/api/getplace/1` ,то вываливается по таймауту. Соответственно с удаленной машины тоже не могу получить данные. Как организовать доступ с удаленных машин ?

У меня в биндингах только одна строчка `type - http , Host Name - localhost, Port - 80, IP Adress - *, Binding INformation - пусто – gregor`

Comment: Разрешил доступ по HTTP, но теперь ошибка 
`404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: в IIS не забыли настроить биндинги?

Comment: Не добавляйте дополнительную информацию в комментарии, используйте редактирование вопроса.

Comment: Ну так у вас биндинг только на локалхлст.

Comment: @tym32167 , Да спасибо!  я  добавил публичный DNS `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com` и все заработало. Это ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить биндинг в IIS для разрешения доступа к вебсайту извне.